# Selection Event is Not Trigger When Clicking Over Row Data

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

My table has defined selection and deselection handlers working fine when the user click over blank space in a row. However, if the user clicks over some text (span tags defined in the table creation), the event is never triggered.

To fix that, I tried to set a row click event handler, which checks if the row has the CSS property 'selected' or not and then trigger manually the corresponding de/selection event over the row. The solution works well when clicking over the text, but unfortunately not when clicking over blank space in a row, because both events are fired and the behaviour is not the expected.

Any idea for handling this?

```
/*
*/
function createTable(){

    if(table != null){//Si la tabla ya existe: eliminamos filas y la destruimos.
        table.destroy();
        $('#'+tableID).empty();
    }

    table = $('#' + tableID).DataTable({
        "dom": 'Bfrtip',
        "buttons":  ['selectAll','selectNone'],
        "columnDefs": [{
            "render": function(data, type, row){
                return '<span class="label bg-info">' + data + '</span>';
            },
            "targets": 1
        },
        {
            "render": function(data, type, row){
                return '<span class="column1">' + data + '</span>';
            },
            "targets": 0
        }],
        "select": {style: 'multi'},
        "data": rows,
        "columns": columns,
        "destroy": true
    });

    table.off('select').on('select', handlerRowsSelection);
    table.off('deselect').on('deselect', handlerRowsDeselection);
    //table.off('click').on( 'click', 'tr', handlerRowClickEvent);
}

/*
*/
function handlerRowClickEvent(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
        table.row(this).deselect();
    }
    else {
        table.row(this).select();
    }
}

/*
*/
function handlerRowsSelection(e, dt, type, indexes){
    if(type=="row"){
        //DOING SOMETHING
    }
}

/*
*/
function handlerRowsDeselection(e, dt, type, indexes){
    if(type=="row"){
        //DOING SOMETHING
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us some code.

Comment: I added some code to the question. Sorry for the delay in posting code.

Comment: Great you updated the question, but I still have some difficulties to replicate, you can work on this fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/687/

Comment: @davidkonrad Here you have a working fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/nespapu/cgomufta/3/  , except for the rows don't mark themselves as selected (only visually, internally the are). But if you see the browser console you can understand the behaviour described in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a basic example on codepen, not sure why yours doesn't work as it appears to be correct. Try altering the codepen one thing at a time to get towards what you have and that might help identify the cause of the issue.

http://codepen.io/carltondickson/pen/VaQzyM

## HTML

```html
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

## CSS

https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css
https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.1.2/css/select.dataTables.min.css

## JS

https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js

https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js

https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.1.2/js/dataTables.select.min.js

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var t = $('#example').DataTable( {
        select: {style: 'multi'}
    } );
    t.off("select").on( "select", function( e, dt, type, indexes ) {
        console.log( "Selected" );
        console.log( e, dt, type, indexes );
    } );
    t.off("deselect").on( "deselect", function( e, dt, type, indexes ) {
        console.log( "Deselected" );
        console.log( e, dt, type, indexes );
    } );
} );
```

Comment: A thorough answer with full code and a working demo. Rude to not acknowledge or accept it. For me the codepen wasn't showing the select event, only the deselect - but there's more than enough here to solve my problem. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition you can check if row is selected and get data:

```
t.off("select").on( "select", function( e, dt, type, indexes ) {
    console.log( "Selected" );
    console.log( e, dt, type, indexes );
    if ( type === 'row' ) {
        var data = t.rows( indexes ).data().pluck( 'id' );
        console.dir(data);
        // do something with data
    }
} );
```